# vscode: stop sending args to specific terminal profile

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a custom tmux terminal defined like this:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "flask server": {
        "path": "tmux",
        "args": ["a", "-t", "server3"],
        "icon": "star",
        "overrideName": true,
        "color": "terminal.ansiRed"
    }
},
```

However the workspace I'm using has a python interpreter configured, and whenever I open this terminal vscode sends the command "source path/to/venv/bin/activate" to it.

How do I stop the default interpreter from being launched on this specific profile?